# Формула для нахождения j в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, циклы, матрицы

Есть готовый метод, x(i) - столбец n элемента, y(j) - столбец, но не я не могу придумать правильную формулу, чтобы найти этот столбец. Есть только его индекс(n), массив 5x5.

```
private int[][] reverse(int[][] arr, int n){
    n=n-1;
    int x = n/arr.length;
    int y = ?;
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++){
            if(x==i || y ==j){
             arr[i][j] = arr[i][j]==0? 1:0;   
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: ваша конечная цель непонятна. вы передаете массив и некую переменную n. судя по названию, вы хотите что-то инвертировать... дайте пример входящего массива и нужного вывода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int[][] reverse(int[][] arr, int n){
    int x = n / arr.length;
    int y = n % arr.length;
    arr[x][y] = arr[x][y]==0? 1:0; 
    return arr;
}
```

Если я верно вас понял, то вам надо поменять цифру в ячейке n на 1 если там 0, если там не ноль, то поставить 1.

```
int x = n / arr.length; - делением получаем сколько массивов надо пропустить
int y = n % arr.length; - остаток от деления показывает какая ячейка нам нужна.
```

Вычитание убрал, т.к. индексация массива идет с нуля и в метод стоит подавать корректный номер ячейки, позаботьтесь об этом в вызывающем методе (не или верните `n--;`)

Comment: Благодарен за помощь!